# Drawing a line from Point to X miles and X degrees,

Tags: uwp, maps

I'm working on a UWP Microsoft Map, and I'm setting a `MapIcon` at a specific location. I was wondering if there's a formula that would allow me to add a `PolyLine` X miles at X degrees?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To elaborate a bit more on Martin's answer.

You should be able to do exactly what you need with [CoordinateSharp](https://github.com/Tronald/CoordinateSharp). Furthermore, if you are worried about overhead, just turn EagerLoading off to turn all the "bloat" off.

If your endpoint was incorrect, check if you are using either reverse bearing or spherical calculations (it happens quite commonly).

```
 //Create Coordinate with EagerLoading off to increase performance
 Coordinate coordinate = new Coordinate(45.000, 27.00, new EagerLoad(false));

 //Create distance (100 KM)
 Distance distance = new Distance(100, DistanceType.Kilometers);

 //Move Coordinate South 100 KM, using Ellipsoidal Earth Calculations
 coordinate.Move(distance, 180, Shape.Ellipsoid); 

 Console.WriteLine(coordinate.Latitude.ToDouble() + " " + coordinate.Longitude.ToDouble()); 
 //Outputs; LAT: 44.1000961768268 - LONG: 27
```